# Synology CloudStation Drive client for Ubuntu fails to start

Tags: linux-mint, qt, nas, synology

I have a Synology NAS, and wanted to try out the CloudStation Drive client for Linux. Downloaded the current deb file for 64bit Ubuntu and installed it. Everything went fine until here.

When I start the client from the menu, nothing happens. When I start it from the console, I get this:

```
craesh@denkbrett ~ $ synology-cloud-station-drive
craesh@denkbrett ~ $ lib path = '/opt/Synology/CloudStation/lib/plugins'
../libcommon/SynoLocale.cpp:64 qPrintable(qstrLocaleLower)=[en_us
] 
../libcommon/SynoLocale.cpp:80 qPrintable(qstrLocaleLower)=[en_us] 
../libcommon/SynoLocale.cpp:161 qPrintable(qstrLangFileName)=[:/enu.qm] 
../libcommon/SynoLocale.cpp:138 qPrintable(qstrDef)=[enu
] 

craesh@denkbrett ~ $
```

Looks like there is a version issue with some QT lib, but don't know which. Any idea?

Version of the deb packet is 4.2.2-4379. I also installed the backup client (same version), which works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the same issue with 4.2.4-4393 on Linux Mint (binary compatible with Ubuntu). I couldn't find anything to get a grip on why it was happening. It was working fine and then suddenly just stopped. CLI invocations, clicking the icon, etc. all died. CLI gave roughly the same output as you had.

My solution was to remove the client, reboot, and re-install. You don't need to completely remove all synced files (I have 18GB of stuff so I'd rather not pull it all down again). When you re-install and run Cloud Station, you will have to reconnect. Just make sure to point the local directory at the existing one and give it a little time to find and update all the files.